# How to get a Certain Consumption Equivalent using Epstein-Zin preferences?

Tags: asset-pricing, utility-theory

In many asset pricing models we use CRRA preferences and Epstein-Zin preferences.

Let's say I have an agent that lives $T$ periods with CRRA preferences:

$$ V_0 = \sum_{t=0}^{T} \beta^t \frac{C_t^{1-\gamma}}{1-\gamma}$$

For a given agent who is optimizing this utility function I can get its value at $t=0$.

So I can ask what is the certain consumption stream $\bar{C}$ that would make the agent indifferent between the stochastic consumption stream $C_t$ and the fixed one, i.e.:

$$ V_0 = \sum_{t=0}^{T} \beta^t \frac{\bar{C}^{1-\gamma}}{1-\gamma}$$

Which implies:

$$\bar{C} = \bigg [ \frac{(1-\gamma)V_0}{\sum_{t=0}^{T} \beta^t}  \bigg ]^{\frac{1}{1-\gamma}}$$

Now suppose I have Epstein-Zin preferences. And I want to compute the certain equivalent. I.e. the preference of the agent are now given by:

$$V_t = \bigg \{ (1-\beta) C_t^{1-1/\psi} + \beta E_t( V_{t+1}^{1-\gamma})^{\frac{1-1/\psi}{1-\gamma}} \bigg \}^{\frac{1}{1-1/\psi}} $$

How would I go about computing this certain equivalent?

Comment: Cross-posted at [Economics SE](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/56351). Please avoid posting on multiple SE sites at once.

Comment: I checked. There is no hard rule against it. It is not recommended but no hard guideline on that. Also to whomever downvoted the question, some feedback would be great.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is [cross-posted](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/56351/how-to-get-a-certain-consumption-equivalent-using-epstein-zin-preferences). Here is a helpful [Q&A on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) about cross-posting.

Comment: @phdstudent, the usual recommendation is not to cross post, especially simultaneously (without waiting a few days for an answer on one site), even if there is no hard rule. I included a link to your other post so that if you get an answer or some useful comments there, people viewing this post would be aware of that possibility. I did not downvote your post.